# First 500MB of RAID6 array is wiped, how to recover?

Tags: raid, ext4, data-recovery, 3ware, raid6

We have a RAID6 array with 12 disks on a 3ware 9650SE-12ML controller. An engineer of our server provider issued this command by mistake: `sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sde  bs=1M count=500; sync;`

`/dev/sde` is the linux device of the raid array.

This wiped the first 500MB of that device. There was no partition on it, device was configured as ext4 file system.

tw-cli show no errors. I haven't tried anything yet. The device is still mounted on the mount point but all the files are gone and it became "Read-only file system".

What information is gone and how can it be recovered?

```
Unit  UnitType  Status         %RCmpl  %V/I/M  Stripe  Size(GB)  Cache  AVrfy
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
u0    RAID-6    OK             -       -       256K    27939.6   RiW    ON

VPort Status         Unit Size      Type  Phy Encl-Slot    Model
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
p0    OK             u0   2.73 TB   SATA  0   -            TOSHIBA DT01ACA300
p1    OK             u0   2.73 TB   SATA  1   -            TOSHIBA DT01ACA300
p2    OK             u0   2.73 TB   SATA  2   -            TOSHIBA DT01ACA300
p3    OK             u0   2.73 TB   SATA  3   -            TOSHIBA DT01ACA300
p4    OK             u0   2.73 TB   SATA  4   -            TOSHIBA DT01ACA300
p5    OK             u0   2.73 TB   SATA  5   -            TOSHIBA DT01ACA300
p6    OK             u0   2.73 TB   SATA  6   -            TOSHIBA DT01ACA300
p7    OK             u0   2.73 TB   SATA  7   -            TOSHIBA DT01ACA300
p8    OK             u0   2.73 TB   SATA  8   -            TOSHIBA DT01ACA300
p9    OK             u0   2.73 TB   SATA  9   -            TOSHIBA DT01ACA300
p10   OK             u0   2.73 TB   SATA  10  -            TOSHIBA DT01ACA300
p11   OK             u0   2.73 TB   SATA  11  -            TOSHIBA DT01ACA300

Name  OnlineState  BBUReady  Status    Volt     Temp     Hours  LastCapTest
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
bbu   On           Yes       OK        OK       OK       0      xx-xxx-xxxx
```

**UPDATE**: We used e2fsck and it recovered superblock information from an alternate location. Device became mountable again. However when we mounted it, there was no file on it.

Comment: I assume `/dev/sde` refers to the RAID-6 volume `u0` in Linux?

Comment: @TeroKilkanen yes that is true, I edited the question.

Comment: There might be a backup superblock somewhere, but that still probably won't get you very far. Your best bet is to restore from backup.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to restore the latest backup.

Otherwise, one can try tools mentioned in Ubuntu's [Data recovery article](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery#Extract_individual_files_from_recovered_image). To be safe, you should create an image of the current state of the RAID volume, and operate on the image.

Comment: I don't think Ubuntu's data recovery article is relevant because those are for cases when data is still intact on disk. Our problem is that certain bytes are set to 0 on the device, so data and filesystem information is gone.

Comment: ext4 stores its superblock in several locations around the disk, and the recovery software should be able to locate a backup copy of the superblock to enable access to filesystem information. http://www.ufsexplorer.com/rdr_ext23.php could be another option.

Comment: Operating on a duplicate image would be the right way to do this, but it's understandable that the array might be too large to take a snapshot of it within budget.  Thing is, you probably *can* recover a lot from this volume.  If you screw up the recovery, you can't.  If the budget is really too constrained, use another machine, reproduce a similar configuration and reproduce the problem.  You might be able to just give the mount command an alternate superblock.  http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/mounting-with-an-alternative-superblock.html